# How to simply set up a file uploader for cronjob in Django?

Tags: python, django, file-upload

All I want to do is to set up a staff-only page in Django to upload some simple .txt files to the server and cronjob will pick it up to do the rest. I have read some docs on file upload in Django but most of them seem a little bit too more, which means I need to create some models first, etc. But in my case, it's just a simple text file for cronjob and I don't wanna make it that complicated. Is there any way to achieve this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own view to upload files without using models. You just need to create a [Django form with FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#filefield) in it and then create the view and the controller, somehow like this:

**views.py**

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form.is_multipart():
            save_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponse('Thanks for uploading the file')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Bad file data.')
    else:
        form = FileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload_file_form.html', {'form': form})

def save_file(file, path=''):
    filename = file._get_name()
    fd = open('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT, str(path) + str(filename)), 'wb')
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        fd.write(chunk)
    fd.close()
```

**upload_file_form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Upload file</h1>
        {% if form.errors %}
            <p style="color: red;">
                Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
            </p>
        {% endif %}

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```